# Find product using summation C# Problem?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to write a simple program to find the product of two numbers (X, Y) without using multiplication. Meaning that I will only use summation to find the product.

I am trying to use the "Divide-and-Conquer" technique, and am using the obviously known concept that:
5*6 = 5+5+5+5+5+5

```
Multiply(uint X, uint Y)
{     
    if (Y < 1)
        return 23423432453; //any very big random number

    if (Y == 1)
        sum = sum + X;

    else // if (Y != 1)
    {
        halfY = Y / 2;
        if (Y % 2 == 0) // if Y is even #
            return Multiply(X, halfY);
        else //if Y is odd #
            return Multiply(X, halfY) + Multiply(X, 1);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

**EXPLANATION**

1) I see the problem as (for example) a 5x6 grid. My idea is to keep recursively dividing the number of columns Y until I reach that Y=1 (Y=1 is the base case). When Y=1, the number of rows in each column would be simply "X" and I can just add X+X+X ... according to the #of columns Y, and save the result in the variable

```
sum
```

, then I just return "sum" at the end.

2) In this part of the code,

```
 else //if Y is odd #
       return Multiply(X, halfY) + Multiply(X, 1);
```

I added "Multiply(X, 1)" to compensate for the "1" that will be lost due to the integer division operation.

----- As an illustration: For example 5*6, where X=5, Y=6:

```
                                Multiply(X,Y)                            //Y=6
                          /                       \
               Multiply(X, Y/2)                   Multiply(X, Y/2)       //Y=3, Y=3
             /         |        \               /      \          \
   Mult(X,Y/4) Mult(X,Y/4) Mult(X,1)  Mult(X,Y/4) Mult(X,Y/4) Mult(X,1) //Y=1,1,1,1,1,1
        |           |           |           |            |        |     //BASE CASE!
```

sum=        X    +      X     +     X      +    X       +    X    +   X
   = 5+5+5+5+5+5
   = 30

---

The code seems pretty logic to me, but it won't give me the right output. Is the idea incorrect? Any help in what is wrong would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you didn't go down the right path as you only called Multiply(X, halfY) once; you need to double the result of the recursive call: (`x*y = 2*(x*y/2)`)

```
var prod = Multiply(X, halfY);
if (Y % 2 == 0) // if Y is even #
    return prod + prod ;
else //if Y is odd #
    return prod + prod  + X;
```

also the global `sum` is unneeded just return X at that point:

```
if (Y == 1)
    return X;
```

Comment: I didn't notice that it was only recursing on 1 side. Thank you very much.